# Which JVM prints out a thread dump like this?

Tags: java, thread-dump

I'm used to see Java thread dumps that look like the following, which is the one that's generated by Sun HotSpot JVMs and their derivatives, such as OpenJDK:

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4020009000 nid=0x538c in Object.wait() [0x00007f402891f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000614ea64e8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.join(QueuedThreadPool.java:386)
    - locked <0x0000000614ea64e8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.join(Server.java:398)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:531)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:364)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:528)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
```

Now, in assisting other users using my software, I occasionally come across another form of thread dumps like this:

```
Thread 9255: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(java.lang.Class) @bci=0, line=63 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(java.nio.ByteBuffer, sun.reflect.ConstantPool, java.lang.Class, boolean) @bci=94, line=202 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(byte[], sun.reflect.ConstantPool, java.lang.Class) @bci=39, line=69 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(byte[], sun.reflect.ConstantPool, java.lang.Class) @bci=11, line=52 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary() @bci=22, line=3070 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(java.lang.Class) @bci=13, line=3029 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.google.inject.internal.Annotations.isRetainedAtRuntime(java.lang.Class) @bci=3, line=57 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.google.inject.Key.ensureRetainedAtRuntime(java.lang.Class) @bci=1, line=362 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.google.inject.Key.strategyFor(java.lang.annotation.Annotation) @bci=15, line=339 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.google.inject.Key.get(com.google.inject.TypeLiteral, java.lang.annotation.Annotation) @bci=6, line=274 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.assistKey(java.lang.reflect.Method, com.google.inject.Key, com.google.inject.internal.Errors) @bci=14, line=522 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.<init>(com.google.inject.Key, com.google.inject.assistedinject.BindingCollector) @bci=306, line=235 (Interpreted frame)
```

As you can see, the format is quite different, and inferior. It does not report on locks it holds on, nor does it report which object it is waiting on.

Does anyone know what family of JavaVMs produce the 2nd style of stack traces? I've never used one myself, and this has been bugging me for a while!

Answer (score 3):

This is the output of jstack (in the Oracle JDK) when ran with the -F option.

Answer (score 2):

This style of thread dump looks like result of `jstack` utility work under `Mac OS X`. This could be related to features of the Mac OS JVM implementation.